# How to Enqueue a Function Style in Wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress

usually I used enqueue like this

```php
wp_enqueue_style( 'mystyle', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/style.css',false,'1.1','all');
```

however a created a custom field and want to enqueue a style that is inside a function

```php
function advanced_css() {
  $advanced_css = get_field('advanced_css');
  echo $advanced_css;
  echo '<style type="text/css">';
  echo $advanced_css;
  echo '</div>';
}
```

how do I call the function?

Answer (score 0):

You call the function like: advanced_css();

I think more your question is WHERE to call that function? Your first snippet is much more correct - that's the way to enqueue in WordPress. However if this style needs to be an editable field stored in the database - you can call the function to output your css pretty well wherever you want it to go. Probably the best place would be using the wp_head or wp_footer hook.

Comment: yes I am familiar with wp head but would like to know doing it in enqueue

Comment: wp_enqueue_style adds a specific file to be enqueued, via URL. If you're getting the CSS from the database, you don't have a URL. Unless you want to somehow on save of your styles from the backend - write the content to a file instead - using wp_enqueue_style isn't the way to add these styles. The way the function in your question is written - you want the wp_head or wp_footer hooks to dump out the styles.

Comment: meaning it is not possible to enqueue a style inside a function?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'inside a function'. Whether its scoped to a function or not isn't the issue here. Its the fact that wp_enqueue_style accepts a URL - and you don't have one. You just have the content of a CSS file, not a file itself. In your first example of what you 'usually' do - that call is normally inside a callback function on a hook like 'wp_enqueue_scripts'. So its still running in a funciton.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try?

```php
add_action('wp_head', 'your_custom_styles');

function your_custom_styles()
{
    $advanced_css = get_field('advanced_css');
    
    echo '<style type="text/css">';
    echo $advanced_css;
    echo '</style>';
}
```

It should print styles in the head tag on your page.

Comment: I want to use enqueue